# Current location on a pdf/UIImage file

Tags: pdf, ios5, uiimage, mapkit

I am trying to make a pdf or UIImage as a map. Is there any way i can integrate Latitude and Longitude in a pdf so that i can show the current location on that pdf file?

I know how to show current location in google map. But i have totally no idea how to replace it with a pdf or UIImage.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to know the bounds of your image, and how it correlates to GPS.  For example, if your image shows the range from latitude 33 degrees to 34 degrees, and longitude -112 to -113 degrees, then you can just map within this range.  You also need to know how big your image is- let's assume 1000x1000.

So, if you have a coordinate at, let's say, 33.25 by -112.25, then your pixel position within the image would be 250,750.

The actual transform for a map is

```
destX = (destMaxX - destMinX) * (sourceX / (sourceMaxX - sourceMinX));
```

In our example,

```
destMaxX = 1000;
destMinX = 0;
sourceX = 33.25;
sourceMaxX = 34;
sourceMinX = 33;
```

Same goes for Y, you just plug in Y everywhere you see X.

Hopefully this gets you on the right track.

Comment: The mapping from geographical coordinates to points in your image also depends on the [projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection) of the map.

Comment: Very true.  However, for mapping a small enough area (say less than a degree in lat or lon - which is still about 70 miles at the equator), the difference becomes so small that it doesn't matter very much.  Plus, for OP I think it may be a lot to take in at once to try to understand both coordinate space conversions and projection conversions.  Thanks for pointing it out though :)

Answer (score 0):

Tim said you how to center and recognize the image like a map, but remember to set `ShowUserLocation=YES`